# MDI Form cannot change cursor

Tags: c#, cursor, mdiparent

I am creating a Windows Form Application using an MDI Form.  In the MDI Form I have a SplitContainer, in Panel1 is a TreeView and I load forms into Panel2.

So far everything works with one exception, I cannot turn off the WaitCursor.  I have tried changing it in code and in the form properties.  Changing it in code does nothing and when I try to change it in the form properties it automatically reverts back to WaitCursor.

What am I missing?

Comment: I believe they are certain restrictions when using MDI forms.

Comment: I found the solution by changing the **UseWaitCursor** property to false.  It was so simple yet I could not find the answer to this anywhere.

Comment: If you solved the issue answer your own question and mark it correct. That way people including you can come back if you forgot the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by changing the UseWaitCursor property to false. It was so simple yet I could not find the answer to this anywhere